# Simple approach for making a basic algorithm for melody-creation?

Tags: algorithm

I have seen several questions here regarding algoritms for music-making. But they all concern algorithms for complex compositions and different styles and approaches.

I am working on a program to create *simple* melodies from the *C Major* scale. I was designing a simple algorithm to do so, but got a little stuck.

I would like to know if this algorithm I'm designing, is a good 'general direction' for acheiving this sort of thing. What do you think of it? Is this a correct way of thinking, or do you recommend another approach?

My current approach involves a melody existing only of 16 quater-notes, divided into four measures (This would be boring because it has no rythm. Only as a start). How it works:

- The program would first randomize four triad-chords from the scale
  (the scale has 7 chords to choose from). Then assigns a chord to each
  one of the four measures.
- After that, the program assigns a quater-note to the first note of each measure. That
  note will be *one of the three notes that form the chord for that
  measure*. (Choosing randomly one of the three).
- Then, the program will assign notes to the 3 remaining slots for each measure. These notes will all be either a 2nd above the previous note, a 2nd below the previous note, a 3rd above the previous note or a 3rd below.

This produces a melody that doesn't necessarily sound good, but it doesn't sounds especially 'bad'. So in a sense, it 'works'.

But as I said, I would like to know if there is a better approach to create an algorithm for simple melody-making, and if there are any problems with my current approach (other than the lack of any rythmic diversity, of course).

Thank you

Comment: Interesting question. You can also add a simple "rhythm melody" by arpeggiating the notes of a chord (for the Cmaj, something like, C E G E C* G E G). 
Going back and forth between the notes and controlling the pitch (say C* is an octave higher than C). I'd think using rand() to select between the notes wouldn't cut it. You need to influence the probability in selecting a note from the triad based on a set of patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bad start, but consider the following critique and suggestions:

Critique:

- The 2nd and 3rd step render the 1st wasteful. You're essentially just choosing one random note to start each measure - the fact that it's part of a triad in that scale is lost in the fact that you allow the program to deviate entirely from that triad. Perhaps you were going for uniqueness of starting notes by making sure they are part of 4 unique triads, but there's so much overlap between triads, it's hardly worth the effort.  Further, from a music theory perspective, simply starting a measure with a note from a triad is not sufficient for that measure to sound like/ represent a certain triad.

Suggestions:

- You ought to start off by playing only the notes of the chosen triad in each measure.  This will lead to more natural-sounding melodies.  Then, experiment with allowing a non-chordal note here or there - one "rule" of music theory is that non-chordal tones should be approached by a half-step or be proceeded by a half-step.  For example, if a given measure has been assigned a C Major chord, a safe sequence which uses a non-chordal tone would be G, G#, E, G (G# being the acceptable non-chordal tone because preceeded by a half-step).  It also so happens that if you approach a non-chordal tone upwards, you should resolve downwards and vice versa; but you can get away without always following that.  Do a Google search for non-chordal tones if you want to find more "rules" like this one.  You may encounter some rather heavy music theory though. Another easy way to infuse nice-sounding non-chordal tones is simply to allow Major and Minor 7ths into each measure

  - You oughtn't to choose any old random 4 triads, unless you want your melody to sound very experimental (read: bad).  One of the simplest and safest chord progressions, as you may know, is I, IV, V, I; this is known as a tonic expansion.  Each of these chords has one or more conventional substitutes; for example, the V chord can be substituted with the vii diminished, producing I, IV, viiDim, I.  You'll notice that the V chord of C Major is G B D and the vii diminished is B D F - they share two of the same notes (B D); therefore the ear usually accepts them as substitutes for each other.  I would pseudo-randomly choose my four chords based on the tonic expansion, allowing for substitutes to I, IV, V, I.
  - At the very least, you should almost certainly begin the melody on tonic, end on tonic, and have the dominant (the fifth note) as the penultimate note.  99% of Western music follows these "rules."

I'm not sure how much music theory you know, but I've studied it a bit and would be happy to point out some more detailed pertinent points if you'd like; though, I think what I've included here is enough for a decent start.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :) Two question: 1- Do you recommend only using the I, IV, V, I progression and it's subtitutes? If so, is there a method to use different and more diverse chords progressions, without telling the program to simply choose from a number of pre-prepared chord progressions?
2- Do you recommend choosing a scale before constructing the chord progression and the melody? If so, let's say the program chose the C Major scale. In this scale, for example the note D doesn't have a note that's close to it by a half step. Does that mean I can't use it over a C Major chord?

Comment: 1. Well, you did say you wanted to make simple melodies; so, if that's still the case, I'd stick with tonic expansion with substitutes.  Maybe once you've done that successfully you can explore less conventional chord progressions.  2. No, I mean choosing a scale is not a bad thing; but its sort of a whole different type of approach than what I've suggested.  Again this could be implemented down the road once you've gotten a solid basis, but I'd wait til then.  I would start by choosing a key (whose triads you've predefined) and doing what I suggested.

Comment: As for the D note in the C Major scale issue - good point.  I was over-simplifying the matter when I said to approach and proceed non-chordal tones by half-step.  The truth is you should do so "step-wise," meaning by Major and Minor 2nds (which are half and whole-steps).  You'll get more natural sounding melodies by "stepping" to the next note in the scale; my example was actually kind of bad.  Since the next step-wise note in the CMaj scale after G is actually A(whole-step), it'd be much better to go G, A, E, G.  But if you were on E in a Cmaj scale you'd do a half-step to F. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a large amount of research done in this area, which is generally called **Algorithmic Composition**.  There's a reasonable overview on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_composition). Such systems are classified into several different types depending on whether you are synthesing the music from a set of rules, or whether you have analysed a large amount of source material in order to generate [Markov Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_model) which encode the likelihood of what the next note will be, given what the previous notes were.

I would suggest reading through many of the papers available to understand more about the problem.  Most of them will refer back to the classic work, Lerdahl and Jackendoff's [Generative Theory of Tonal Music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_theory_of_tonal_music)